# Как ограничить вывод только для страниц с категориями товаров?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, if, условия

Есть интернет-магазин на wordpress+woocommerce. Хочу вывести определенную информацию для страниц с категориями товаров (и только!), но если задаю варианты условий:

```
if(is_archive()) {..}
```

или

```
if(is_archive('product')) {..}
```

то тоже самое выводится и на страницах с рубриками статей. Как ограничить вывод только для страниц с категориями товаров?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, правильная функция для вывода:

```
function mad_is_product_category( $term = '' ) {
    return is_tax( 'product_cat', $term );
}
```

оказывается, все гораздо проще - есть специальная функция `is_product_category()` для этих целей

Answer (score 0):

Правильный код

```
$query_object = get_queried_object();
if ( is_object( $query_object ) && $query_object->taxonomy == 'product_cat' && ( $query_object->slug == 'abstraction' || $query_object->term_id == 30 ) ) {
    echo 'Спец текст для категории';
}
```

`( $query_object->slug == 'abstraction' || $query_object->term_id == 30 )` - можно по слагу определить или по `term_id`, как будет удобней.

Код вставить в файле `woocommerce/archive-product.php`